# How to make default select the first item in mat-list in angular

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-material

I wanna know how to make default select the first item of mat-list in angular. I tried but not able to resolve it. My mat-list code is here

```js
export class StationsListComponent implements OnInit {

  @Input() stations: Stations[];
  selectedStation: Stations;

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.selectedStation = this.stations[0];
  }
}
```

```html
<mat-list role="list">
  <div *ngFor="let book of Books">
    <mat-list-item id="{{book.bookId}}" role="listitem" class="list-item" routerLink="/home/{{book.bookId}}" [routerLinkActive]="['is-active']">
      <div class="station-div">
          <div class="station-name">{{book.bookName}}</div>
          <div class="station-location">{{book.authorName}}</div>
      </div>
    </mat-list-item>
  </div>
</mat-list>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to the [Angular Material Docs](https://material.angular.io/components/list/api), `mat-list-item` doesn't have a selected input property that you can apply to the element. however `mat-list-option` does.

as such, if you switch to using mat-list-option you can leverages properties `[selected]` and `[value]`

Comment: so what should I use can give me a demo code. and Thankyou :)

Answer (score 12):

You could use a 'mat-selection-list' and specify which entry you want to be selected by default by editing the [selected] value:

```
<mat-selection-list #itemList>
    <mat-list-option *ngFor="let item of items, let i = index" [selected]="item && i == 0">
      #{{i+1}} {{ item.name }}
    </mat-list-option>
</mat-selection-list>
```

In this case the first item would be selected by default, because [selected]="item && i == 0". If you change "i == 0" to "i == 1" the second item is selected an so on.

Comment: Meanwhile the accepted answer is good enough for experienced devs, I would much rather prefer this answer. Just because there is a working code sample showing how it works. Thank you Gereon99. Now, take my upvote.

Comment: This is the best answer and I agree that should be marked as accepted